# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Expected a value of type 'List<dynamic>', but got one of type '_JsonMap'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, rest, json-serialization

I am new to flutter. Am trying to consume a Rest_Api from my UI to make a get Request,however i am getting an error **"Expected a value of type 'List', but got one of type '_JsonMap'"**,which have tried to debug based on the suggestions found online but I can't seem to solve this issue. Here is a screenshot of the error am getting:
[image]

Here is my **model** and **service** classes:

```js
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
part 'unit.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Unit {
  String ? id;
  String name;
  String baseUnit;
  var baseValue;

  Unit({
    this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.baseUnit,
    required this.baseValue,
  });
  factory Unit.fromJson(Map < String, dynamic > json) => _$UnitFromJson(json);
  Map < String, dynamic > toJson() => _$UnitToJson(this);
}
```

```js
Future < List < Unit >> search(searchText, page) async {
  var searchUrl = "${ApiEndPoint.baseUrl}/unit?q=$searchText&page=$page";
  var response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(searchUrl),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
  );
  var units = convert.json.decode(response.body) as List;
  List < Unit > unitList = [];
  unitList = units.map((i) => Unit.fromJson(i)).toList();
  // print(unitList.length);
  // print(response.body);
  return unitList;
}
```

Serialized Model Class is;

```js
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'unit.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// JsonSerializableGenerator
// **************************************************************************

Unit _$UnitFromJson(Map < String, dynamic > json) {
  return Unit(
    id: json['id'] as String ? ,
    name : json['name'] as String,
    baseUnit: json['baseUnit'] as String,
    baseValue: json['baseValue'],
  );
}

Map < String, dynamic > _$UnitToJson(Unit instance) => < String, dynamic > {
  'id': instance.id,
  'name': instance.name,
  'baseUnit': instance.baseUnit,
  'baseValue': instance.baseValue,
};
```

**What could I be doing wrong?**

Comment: which one is line 187? share the json response.

Comment: @Benyamin Here is the json response:
Response:{"page":1,"pages":1,"pageSize":20,"totalRows":4,"units":[{"id":"fed0b37c-4f11-4169-9e53-c5553e106936","name":"m²","baseUnit":"m²","baseValue":1.0},{"id":"d896b847-7cbf-48e5-963b-0e7d79a51f40","name":"ft²","baseUnit":"m²","baseValue":0.092903},{"id":"04b55ad0-5367-49ce-850f-2ab6fe184bc6","name":"feet","baseUnit":"ft","baseValue":0.536127},{"id":"684656a6-6e7d-4b0d-af5e-c7c1247ac9af","name":"inche","baseUnit":"in","baseValue":1.536127}]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change to change the return value in the service to this and somehow it worked.

```js
Future < List < UnitSearch >> search(searchText, page) async {
  var searchUrl = "${ApiEndPoint.baseUrl}/unit?q=$searchText&page=$page";
  http.Response response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(searchUrl),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
  );
  final data = json.decode(response.body);
  return List < UnitSearch > .from(
    data['units'].map((item) => UnitSearch.fromJson(item)));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var units = convert.json.decode(response.body) as List;
```

your response returns JSON object but you are casting as List.
Your response is:

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "pages": 1,
  "pageSize": 20,
  "totalRows": 4,
  "units": [
    {
      "id": "fed0b37c-4f11-4169-9e53-c5553e106936",
      "name": "m²",
      "baseUnit": "m²",
      "baseValue": 1
    },
    {
      "id": "d896b847-7cbf-48e5-963b-0e7d79a51f40",
      "name": "ft²",
      "baseUnit": "m²",
      "baseValue": 0.092903
    },
    {
      "id": "04b55ad0-5367-49ce-850f-2ab6fe184bc6",
      "name": "feet",
      "baseUnit": "ft",
      "baseValue": 0.536127
    },
    {
      "id": "684656a6-6e7d-4b0d-af5e-c7c1247ac9af",
      "name": "inche",
      "baseUnit": "in",
      "baseValue": 1.536127
    }
  ]
}
```

I guess you are trying to get list of units from response. if so try this:

```
var units = (convert.json.decode(response.body) as Map<String,dynamic>)["units"];
```

Comment: yes I am trying to get the list of units from the response.However, with your suggestion, I now get another error i.e "Error: Expected a value of type 'List<Unit>', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>'"

Comment: @Emmon Everything you need is to convert List<dynamic> To list of unit. `var converted = List<Unit>.from(units);`